# EXT4-fs (sdc): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem

Tags: fedora, filesystems, mount, hard-disk

In short, this is where I found the best answers to my problem with my disks: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

---

During Fedora 15 installation, I added all my 3 drives to be mounted on boot. However, after the installation ended I could not mount them any more.

During the reboot, I was presented with this message?

```
**Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D for normal startup):**
```

"Control-D" did not work and I ended turning off manually and reinstalling Fedora 14, in the hope it was a bug, but, as I knew latter, it was not.

So I tried to added the disks manually in fstab:

```
$ nano /etc/fstab
/dev/sdb1                /media/Unus                     ext4     defaults  0 0
/dev/sdc1                /media/Duo                     ext4     defaults       0 0
```

But they do not mount:

```
$ mount media/Duo
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

This is what I get from dmesg:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[  897.592207] EXT4-fs (sdc): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

However, the disks are there:

```
$ testDisk

Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - ATA ST31000528AS
Disk /dev/sdc - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - ATA ST2000DL003-9VT1

Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
    Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
>   P ext4                     0   0  1 121601  80 63 1953525168 [Unus]

Disk /dev/sdc - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63
    Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
>   P Unknown                  0   0  1 243201  80 63 3907029168
```

Note that just before installing Fedora 15, both disks were formatted with ext4 and were working normally.

Is there a way to rebuild the filesystem without losing the data recorded on the disks?

I wish to know what I should do, as both disks have indispensable data in them.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

Following: http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

As root I ran:

```
$ fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/sdb
```

And this recovered one of my disks. So I could mount it:

```
$ mkdir /media/Unus && mount /dev/sdb
```

However, I was not so lucky with the other:

```
$ fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

As someone suggested, I ran:

```
$ file -s /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdb1: ACB archive data
/dev/sdc1: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: XlSIOVm3e8Ozqv4EO0TgTCiKAOdW4V6
```

Now I am figuring out how to fix disk /dev/sbc - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - ATA ST2000DL003-9VT1 (which was **ext4**, by the way).

---

```
# e2fsck -n /dev/sdc1

e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Some print screens of the disks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQwDL.jpg

---

**LAST UPDATE**

While I am waiting for the new disk to arrive, I was trying some of your suggestions.

In order to try to activate a logical volume, I got this:

```
# lvchange -ay vg_atipico/**lv_duo**
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
```

Did I write the command right or should I write instead:

"lvchange -ay vg_atipico/**sdc1**" ?

Comment: What does `file -s /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1` say? What about `e2fsck -n /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`?

Comment: I have updated the question above with you answer, @Gilles. Thank you very much, by the way.

Comment: If the data is that important and you have no backup, the first thing to do is make a full copy of its current state, before you risk making things worse. ou will probably manage to recover *most* of the data by yourself, but a professional is likely to do better; it's up to you to decide whether the cost is worth it. What type of data is on the disk? (e.g. small/large files, of what type, do the file names matter, …)

Comment: @Gilles, thank you again. I'll do what I got to do. There are all sorts of data in this 2 TB disk, all types. Some of this data do has backup, but not all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **don't do anything destructive until you understand exactly what's going on**. For example, don't run `e2fsck` without `-n` on a device unless you're absolutely sure that the device contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem and that you're in a position to recover it.

Before risking anything destructive, I recommend that you **make a copy** of the raw disks. Get a disk that's at least as large and copy the whole thing:

```
cat </dev/sdb >/dev/sdd
```

(where the disk to save is `/dev/sdb` and you want to overwrite `/dev/sdd` — be very careful not to get a single letter wrong!).

`/dev/sdb` seems to be in an inconsistent state. Apparently it has a partition table that indicates that there is a partition `/dev/sdb1`, and at the same time it has a filesystem on the whole disk rather than on the partition. If there is indeed a filesystem on the whole disk, there shouldn't be a partition table. Given that you've already done something potentially destructive, I recommend you try copying all the files off the disk. Mount it as read-only:

```
mkdir /media/b
mount -r -t ext4 /dev/sdb /b
cp -a /media/b /some/place/you/have/enough/space
```

`/dev/sdc1` contains an [LVM physical volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29). You need to assemble this volume. In fact, the system may have done that already; the data is on the logical volume, not directly on the partition. Run `lvs` to see what logical volumes are available.

```
mkdir /media/c
lvs   # You'll probably see a line with "  volumegroupname    logicalvolumename"
mount -r -t ext4 /dev/mapper/volumegroupname-logicalvolumename /media/c
```

If `lvs` doesn't show anything, you'll need to activate the volumes first. Run `vgs` to see a list of available volume groups, `vgchange -ay volumegroupname` to activate a volume group, `lvchange -ay volumegroupname/logicalvolumename` to activate a logical volume. If you need help, post the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`.

---

You can try to recover the filesystem structure even if `e2fsck` doesn't manage. But this requires deep knowledge of the filesystem. Even a professional may or may not get far, depending on precisely which bits were overwritten. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a filesystem recovery tool; try unleashing it on your disk.

If you don't manage to repair the filesystem, go fishing for individual files. This may be easy or difficult depending on what kinds of files you're after and how the disk is laid out. A favorable case is large video files that were all written in one go (so each file has a recognizable header and is likely to be unfragmented). An unfavorable case is a tree of source code where you'll have a lot of versions of each file (all but one deleted) and even associating file data with names is part of the difficulty.

There are [tools](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools%3aData_Recovery#Carving) that go looking for recognizable files on a damaged filesystem (or erased files), mostly images and videos and sounds. The TestDisk website has a [list of data recovery distributions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd); [CAINE](http://www.caine-live.net/), in particular, is a live distribution specialized in forensics.

Comment: I have updated my question with the data you was talking about. All this operation is absolutely new to me. I promise not to make anything stupid in the next 10 minutes :-)

Comment: Would this tool help in something? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: @Roger It might. If you had an ext4 volume before on `/dev/sdc`, you've now overwritten bits of it to make an LVM physical volume. What does `e2fsck -n /dev/sdc1` report? I suggest making a full copy of the disk and running `e2fsck -y` *on the copy*. You might be able to recover most files that way. Separately, try the tools in TestDisk; they're likely to be more complicated and more tedious to write, but should be able to recover more files that haven't actually been overwritten. You probably have lost at least a little data.

Comment: Once I copied the files to a new disk, what would be the steps from there? Is there a possibility to recover the filesystem in order the data is once again available? Or the procedure is to go straight to try to save the biggest amount of data possible?

Comment: @Roger See my additions on how to copy the disk and recovery tools that may help you. Try to repair the filesystem first, but be prepared that it may not work. If it doesn't you can still go after the contents of files.

Comment: thank you again. While trying to know more about how to recover the disks I found ddrecover (and dd_recover). Here are some examples: http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue

Comment: While searching for a step by step that I can use to add for the tips you have already given me, I found this very useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery